# Swagger @ApiResponses as constant value

Tags: java, annotations, swagger

I use swagger to create a RESTful API, and have several endpoints which return the same errors and responses:

```
 @GET
    @Path("/some/endpoint")    
    @ApiOperation(
        value = "Some method", 
        notes = "Some method")
    @ApiResponses(
        value = { 
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = RestConstants.HTTP_200, response = Response.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = RestConstants.HTTP_400, response = Error.class),        
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = RestConstants.HTTP_401, response = Error.class),        
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = RestConstants.HTTP_403, response = Error.class),        
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = RestConstants.HTTP_404, response = Error.class), 
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = RestConstants.HTTP_500, response = Error.class) 
        })    
    public Response someMethod(){...}
```

The amount of @ApiResonses is may about to change. As of now, I need to declare all of theses for my individual endpoint methods.
Is there a way to use a constant value as an @ApiResponses value, e.g. like:

```
@ApiResponses(value = MY_RESPONSES)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unfortunately isn't possible using the Swagger annotations.
For this to work `ApiResponse` would have to be a normal class/interface rather than an annotation.

Comment: That's too bad. It means a lot of redundant and not easy to maintain code :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that: If your Problem is, that 'All' endpoints give same API-Responses, you can annotate the whole controller with:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(...), @ApiResponse(...)...})<br>
public class Controller{...}
```

And if you have a endpoint, that has another APIResponse, just add it to `@Operation(response={here})`